# Mysql Query Or Laravel Eloquent for Average of multiple column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Here  two tables.

table1:Customer

```
+----+-------+-------------+--------+
| id | Ip_Id | Customer_Id | Class  |
+----+-------+-------------+--------+
| 1  | 100   | A           | First  |
| 2  | 100   | B           | First  |
| 3  | 100   | C           | First  |
| 4  | 101   | D           | First  |
| 5  | 101   | E           | First  |
| 6  | 100   | F           | Second |
+----+-------+-------------+--------+
```

table2:Customer_Usage

```
+-------+-------------+----------------+--------+------------+
| Ip_Id | Customer_Id | Customr _Usage | Amount | Date       |
+-------+-------------+----------------+--------+------------+
| 100   | A           | 10             | 100    | 21-02-2020 |
| 100   | B           | 20             | 200    | 22-02-2020 |
| 100   | A           | 30             | 500    | 23-03-2020 |
| 100   | B           | 40             | 500    | 24-02-2020 |
+-------+-------------+----------------+--------+------------+
```

The condition is while enter a value for search Ip_Id, example for 100 it will give a result  like below. make average of the values from the date. How to make a joint and calculate average two columns  Avg _Usage,Avg_Amount for these two tables in Laravel using Mysql

Result:

```
+-------+-------------+------------+------------+
| Ip_Id | Customer_Id | Avg _Usage | Avg_Amount |
+-------+-------------+------------+------------+
| 100   | A           | 20         | 300        |
| 100   | B           | 30         | 350        |
+-------+-------------+------------+------------+
```

Am using below query.

```
$results  = DB::table('Customer')
->select('Customer.Ip_Id','Customer.Customer_Id', 'Customer_Usage.Usage')
->where('Ip_Id', 100)                
->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [method-join](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#joins) to join `Customer` table and `Customer_Usage` table,

And [groupBy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) `CustomerId` for calculating the average of `Customr_Usage` and `Amount` in each group.

```php
$results  = DB::table('Customer')
              ->select('Customer.Ip_Id','Customer.Customer_Id', DB::raw('AVG(Customer_Usage.Customr_Usage) AS Avg_Usage'), DB::raw('AVG(Customer_Usage.Amount) AS Avg_Amount'))
              ->join('Customer_Usage', 'Customer_Usage.customer_id', '=', 'Customer.customer_id')
              ->where('Customer.Ip_Id', 100)
              ->groupBy('Customer.Customer_Id')              
              ->get();
```

Comment: TsaiKoga Again You saved me

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AVG`, `groupBy` and `raw` query for the same;

```
   DB::table('Customer')
   ->selectRaw('Customer.Ip_Id','Customer.Customer_Id', 'AVG(Customer_Usage) as Avg_Usage',  'AVG(Amount) as Avg_Amount')
   ->join('Customer_Usage', 'Customer_Usage.customer_id', '=', 'Customer.customer_id')
   ->where('Ip_Id', 100)                
   ->groupBy("Customer_Id")
   ->get();
```

[Laravel -> Queries -> raw method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-methods)

Comment: How could it make sense to return usage alongside average usage?